# Only constant curves rectifiable

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

I would need a hint on the following standard exercise. Let $0 < a < 1$ and $(X,d)$ a metric space. Let $d^a$ be the corresponding snowflake metric $d^a(x,y) = (d(x,y))^a$. Show that the only rectifiable curves are the constants.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a non-constant curve $\gamma \colon[0,1] \to X$. Without loss of generality, let $d(\gamma(0),\gamma(1)) = 1$.

Since $\gamma$ is continuous, and $x \mapsto d(\gamma(0),x)$ also, the function $\delta \colon [0,1] \to X;\;\delta(t) = d(\gamma(0),\gamma(t))$ is continuous, hence for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, there is a partition $t_0 = 0 < t_1 < t_2 < \dotsc < t_n = 1$ of $[0,1]$ with $\delta(t_k) = \frac{k}{n}$. What can you say about

$$\sum_{k=1}^n d^a(\gamma(t_k),\gamma(t_{k-1}))\;?$$